# strange behavior of box-shadow animation

Tags: html, css

I got this strange behavior with my box-shadows and do not know where it is coming from.

Does anybody know how to prevent this from happening? (Video at the end) 
Code is the following:

```
.w-logos.style_1 .w-logos-item {
    border: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    margin-left:30px;
    filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(200%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.01px;
    transition: all 0.5s; }


.no-touch .w-logos.style_1 .w-logos-item:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: grayscale(0%) contrast(100%);
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 60px -40px;
}
```

[Link to the video on Youtube.com](https://youtu.be/8KrF1JwcYdY)

in case you want to check the real webpage: http://neu.wu-marketingclub.at (it's at the bottom of the main page)

thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: make the transition linear ..  `transition: all 0.5s linear`

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css style has another problem in `Firefox` browser :

[image]

remove this line `box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.01px;` from `.w-logos.style_1 .w-logos-item {`
and add `transition: all 0.5s linear;` to `:hover`

for me in both firefox and chrome it works fine with this change.

> Update: it should solve safari hover problem:

```
    .no-touch .w-logos.style_1 .w-logos-item:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: grayscale(0%) contrast(100%);
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 60px -40px #333;
 box-shadow:0 0 60px -40px #333;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help/reply. This seems to solve the problem in firefox and chrome for me. However it doesnt solve it on safari - I do not really understand why tho - any Idea?

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler i checked it in safari for windows and iPhone the hover effect was fine, unfortunately i don't have any mac to check it.but i guess it would be fine.

Comment: I see, I dont know what the reason is for that behaviour tho, did you have that problem I was talking about in Firefox before you added your solution? 

Sure! :)

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler i guess i find out how to solve this , i updated my answer.